# What is the difference between Editor count and Copy Editor tag?

Tags: support, badges

This might be more of a full fledged Meta.SE question, but will ask it here anyway ...

What is the difference between the [User::Editor](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all) count and the requirement for [copy editor badge](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor)? If I look at the first link, it shows that I have 474 edits. If I go through the  [Review Page](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts) and pull up and one of the six categories (in this case First Posts), then hover over the bar which shows progress, a little box pops which shows my progress towards getting the Copy Editor badge is at 282.

**Why the discrepancy?** Or is there something I don't understand about how the count is attributed to the Copy Editor badge?

Comment: I was going to answer, and as I was typing my answer and double checking to make sure it was correct, it turns out I have no idea...lol

Comment: @Larry ... well I guess that makes two of us, lol!

Comment: Perhaps the editor count includes tag-only edits and the copy editor doesn't? I have 140 and 132 respectively...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top editors list counts all edits (titles, bodies, tags) to 3rd-party posts (questions, answers, tag wikis and tag excerpts) that are not currently deleted.

The criteria for the editing badges are roughly the same, with the notable exception that **they do not count tag-only edits!**

So if you have a significant number of tag edits without corresponding edits to titles and bodies in your editing history, you may find yourself hitting 500 edits on the editors page long before you're awarded the Copy Editor badge.

#### See also: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: Very kewl. Thank you so much for the answer ... had no clue, but thought it was something along this line.